# How do I print line number with the output for JQ in json file

Tags: json, jq

I know there is a -n option and tried many combinations but couldn't get it to work. I'd like to print the line number and the length of the each line for the json file

```
cat -n traffictest.json | jq '. |length'

jq -C . | cat -n traffictest.json | jq '. |length'
```

Comment: The -n option has nothing to do with line-numbering. Also, please give a sample input with expected output. See stackoverflow.com/help/mcve – peak 2 hours ago

Answer (score 4):

jq has a built-in filter, `input_line_number`, which emits the line number of the input being read.  For example, given this input:

```
[1,2]

"abcd"

{"a":1,"b":1,"c":1,"d":1, "e":1}
```

the invocation:

```
jq -r "\(input_line_number): \(length)"
```

yields:

```
1: 2
3: 4
5: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in line-number and length, I would use `awk` instead, e.g.:

```
awk '{ print NR, length, $0 }' traffictest.json
```

Or if you want to keep the syntax highlighting:

```
paste <(jq    . traffictest.json | awk '{ print NR, length }' OFS='\t') \
      <(jq -C . traffictest.json)
```